# No new line character after reading a file and storing result in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, newline

Is there a way to detect the new line character after I've read from a file and stored the results into a string? Here is the code:

```
with open("text.txt") as file:
    content_string = file.read()
    file.close()

re.search("\n", content_string)
```

The content_string looks like this:

```
Hello world!
Hello WORLD!!!!!
```

I want to extract the new line character after the first line "Hello world!". Does this character even exist at that point?

Comment: The `re.search` line detects the newline, doesn'it? You just don't *do* anything with the result.

Comment: `content_string.endswith('\n')`

Comment: How about if I have more lines, and I want to detect the first newline? For some reason, in my text it won't detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Jongware comment, the regex search you perform finds the newline. You just need to use that result.

From the [re module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

**re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)**

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches
>   the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length
>   match at some point in the string.

In terms of code, checking that translates into:

```
with open("text.txt") as file:
    content_string = file.read()
    file.close()

m = re.search("\n", content_string)
if m:
    print "Found a newline"
else:
    print "No newline found"
```

Now, your file might very well contain "\r" rather than "\n": they print likely the same, but the regex would not match. In that case, give also this test a try, replacing the correct line in the code:

```
m = re.search("\n", content_string)
```

with:

```
m = re.search("[\r\n]", content_string)
```

which will look for either.

Comment: I actually edited my question, please the last part.

Comment: You are asking to find a newline: the regex will find it if there is one in the string, doesn't matter if first or last or multiple. Any variations on the match that you want to perform, can be done by adequately  updating the regular expression pattern that you have inside your re.search() statement.

Comment: @KidSudi: I updated the solution: you might have \r instead of \n in your file. Test this solution out.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to detect the new line character after I've read from a
>   file and stored the results into a string?

If I understand you correctly, you want to concatenate multiple lines into one string.
Input:

```
Hello world!
Hello WORLD!!!!!
```

test.py:

```
result = []
with open("text.txt", "rb") as inputs:
    for line in inputs:
        result.append(line.strip())  # strip() removes newline charactor

print " ".join([x for x in result])
```

output:

```
Hello world! Hello WORLD!!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

> How about if I have more lines, and I want to detect the first
>   newline? For some reason, in my text it won't detect it.

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
    print(first_line)
```